# RAM/Memory less than installed

Tags: ram

So i have 8GB RAM installed on my laptop. It shows 8GB in BIOS and on windows boot but when i log in to Ubuntu, only 2GB of Memory reflects.

I cant understand how to utilize my computer at full functionality.

output for free -h

```
$ free -h 
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem: 2,0G        1,1G        132M        320M        829M        402M
Swap:          7,5G        1,0G        6,5G
```

output for sudo dmidecode -t memory

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 1

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: SK Hynix
    Serial Number: 00493032
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

I am attaching a screenshot of the same for better view.
[view of terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9mYa.png)

output for grep command

```
zaidshakil@Zaid-Ubuntu:~$ grep -i cgroup /var/log/syslog*
Apr  1 02:19:09 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 02:19:09 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 02:19:10 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[14939]: time="2017-04-01T02:19:10.982530054+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 02:19:10 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[14939]: time="2017-04-01T02:19:10.982549819+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 15:30:45 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 15:30:45 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 15:30:51 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1206]: time="2017-04-01T15:30:51.597146555+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 15:30:51 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1206]: time="2017-04-01T15:30:51.597157997+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 14:37:30 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 14:37:30 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 14:37:34 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1312]: time="2017-04-01T14:37:34.589461797+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 14:37:34 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1312]: time="2017-04-01T14:37:34.589469876+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 14:56:40 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 14:56:40 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 14:56:43 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1239]: time="2017-04-01T14:56:43.260545225+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 14:56:43 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1239]: time="2017-04-01T14:56:43.260717199+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 18:34:08 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[9228]: time="2017-04-01T18:34:08.790148286+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 18:34:08 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[9228]: time="2017-04-01T18:34:08.790218963+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 18:35:31 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[9383]: time="2017-04-01T18:35:31.250522713+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 18:35:31 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[9383]: time="2017-04-01T18:35:31.250563699+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 18:38:08 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[10604]: time="2017-04-01T18:38:08.740614885+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 18:38:08 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[10604]: time="2017-04-01T18:38:08.740689843+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 19:12:12 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 19:12:12 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 19:12:16 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1314]: time="2017-04-01T19:12:16.925265862+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 19:12:16 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1314]: time="2017-04-01T19:12:16.925280062+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 19:28:59 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[6356]: time="2017-04-01T19:28:59.190885292+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 19:28:59 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[6356]: time="2017-04-01T19:28:59.190944277+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 21:08:20 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  1 21:08:20 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  1 21:08:25 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1345]: time="2017-04-01T21:08:25.398993195+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  1 21:08:25 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1345]: time="2017-04-01T21:08:25.399004818+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  1 21:25:52 Zaid-Ubuntu snap[2201]: time="2017-04-01T21:25:52+02:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="read /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/docker/21b666be1ea4d12abeee0c949f578946b3dff173fe70b417eccbf168f7b6fb46/freezer.state: no such device"
Apr  1 22:09:01 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  2 19:08:15 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  2 19:08:15 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  2 19:08:20 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1340]: time="2017-04-02T19:08:20.939806472+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  2 19:08:20 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1340]: time="2017-04-02T19:08:20.939814976+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  2 18:00:33 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  2 18:00:33 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  2 18:00:37 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1333]: time="2017-04-02T18:00:37.716538593+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  2 18:00:37 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1333]: time="2017-04-02T18:00:37.716554988+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Apr  3 12:40:22 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Apr  3 12:40:22 Zaid-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts..
Apr  3 12:40:29 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1317]: time="2017-04-03T12:40:29.374244538+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Apr  3 12:40:29 Zaid-Ubuntu dockerd[1317]: time="2017-04-03T12:40:29.374252542+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `free -h` and `sudo dmidecode -t memory` to it?

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: @rmustakos i am running a 64 bit ubuntu. I will add outputs of free -h and sudo dmidecode -t memory to my question

Comment: In `terminal` type `grep -i cgroup /var/log/syslog*` and see if that output gives you any clues.

Comment: I am not sure what i am looking for in that log. But nothing on the memory is mentioned! @heynnema

Comment: I don't see anything in the cgroup output. What may be happening is that the memory stick is correctly reporting its size to the OS, but it's defective, and only 2G is usable. In Windows, it also reports 8G RAM, but how do you know what is actually available/usable to the OS? If you load up a bunch of apps, can you see something greater than 2G being used? Lastly, in Ubuntu, you could also `grep -i mem /var/log/syslog*` or `grep -i memory /var/log/syslog*` and look for memory errors.

Comment: I have checked in windows and figured that indeed apps that take up more than 2gb space are functioning. I used CAD on my laptop on windows and it works, which makes me think this is so strange. also, my laptop is installed with 2x4gb ram, i am not sure why a computer would recognize a 2gb stick when there isnt one!

i am not sure what you are looking with in the grep but there are no memory errors there! @heynnema

Comment: If you have 2x4G RAM, dmidecode is showing 8G, but only 1 device in Bank A. I'd expect 2 devices, one in Bank A and one in Bank B. How many physical RAM slots do you have? 2? 4? I'd power off the computer, remove the battery, hold down the power button for 5-10 seconds to drain any residual power, and then reseat the RAM sticks.

Comment: the only issue with that is, i dont have a set of screw drivers right now, besides how is it working fine in windows?

Comment: Did the laptop come with 8G RAM, or did you upgrade it?

Comment: it came with an 8gb ram

Comment: I'd get a screwdriver and try to reseat the RAM sticks first. If that doesn't allow `free -h` and `dmidecode` to show correctly, then I'd remove one stick and retry `free -h`and it should show 4G RAM, then try the other stick in the same slot, `free -h` again and see 4G RAM, then try the sticks, one at a time, in the other slot (I'm assuming that you only have 2 physical RAM slots). I obviously think you have a RAM or RAM slot problem.

Comment: I will get hold of a screwdriver and update hopefully today then. thank you so much

Comment: @heynnema hey, i got the wrong set of screwdrivers.. i didnt realise my laptop needs an Allen Key and not a normal set of screw drivers! so i will have to go look for them again.

Comment: @heynnema hey, how you doing? dorry to reply so late. I checked my bios version and its upto date. I just managed to take my RAM out and clean it and put it back again and its still the same. I can confirm that i have 1 8gb stick as the version of yoga that i own has only one memory slot! weird i know!

Comment: @ZaidShakil thanks for the update. One 8G RAM (instead of 2 x 4) now makes the reports look correct. If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, does the memory report correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing htop and run htop from the terminal and see the output.

```
Open up an SSH session.
Log in with your root user log in credentials.
Type “apt-get install htop”.
To run htop, type “htop”.
If you wish to quit htop at any point, press F10
```

It should show you a bar with all available RAM and how much there is in use. Its a better way of displaying usage of the system that top in my opinion. It also allows you to sort processes by RAM usage.

Comment: Hey, I tried doing that and the bar still shows only 2GB available instead of 8! Any help?

Comment: What is the output of: sudo lshw -class memory

Comment: *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 7
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB

if thats what you are looking for?

Comment: Yup, your system has 8GB and can see 8GB. How it uses that memory is a completely different issue. You said Windows can see 8GB. I am not sure what setup you use, but if its dual boot, I have seen other topics from other people in the past giving them added complexity with abnormal behaviour.  Not sure how a dual boot affects the usage, if at all.

Comment: HEY, Yes i am using the system on dualboot. I am not getting a way to fix this really!

Comment: If you really want to make sure that you have more than 2GB, try creating a RAMDISK in Ubuntu that is slightly bigger than 2GB. This will give you evidence if Ubuntu is capable of using more than 2GB ram for a specific operation or not. If that fails, it means something else is consuming your RAM.

Comment: I have tried that method and ubuntu is capable!